# Не работает compass в gulp

Tags: sass, gulp, compass

gulpfile.js

```js
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    compass = require('gulp-compass');
 
gulp.task('compass', function() {
  gulp.src('scss/*.scss')
    .pipe(compass({
      config_file: './config.rb',
      css: 'stylesheets',
      sass: 'scss'
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('scss'));
});
```

config.rb

```js
preferred_syntax = :sass
http_path = "/"
css_dir = 'stylesheets'
sass_dir = 'scss'
relative_assets = true
line_comments = true
```

main.scss

```html
h1 {
 color: green;
 @include text-shadow(rgba(blue, 0.2) 1px 1px 0, rgba(blue, 0.2) 2px 2px 0, rgba(blue, 0.2) 3px 3px 0);

}
```

Здравствуйте, помогите пожалуйста решить данную проблему. При запуске GULP, sass нормально компилируется, а mixin compass не хотят работать. Пишет: "Error:     error scss/main.scss (Line 3: Undefined mixin 'text-shadow'.)" .

Comment: `main.scss` забыли.

Comment: h1 {
 color: green;
 @include text-shadow(rgba(blue, 0.2) 1px 1px 0, rgba(blue, 0.2) 2px 2px 0, rgba(blue, 0.2) 3px 3px 0);

}

Comment: scss элементарный, все работает до тог момента, пока не добавлю любой @include с документации compass

Comment: Все детали о вопросе -- в вопрос.

Comment: Решение: нужно подключить import "compass/css3". Помогли на Тостер.ру. Всем спасибо!!!

Comment: Так вы добавите SCSSку в вопрос, или его надо закрывать, если вы им уже не займётесь?

Comment: Добавил, решение уже есть, так что при надобности можете закрывать. Спасибо.

Comment: Почти. Только уберите оттуда решение и запостите ответом. :) У нас всё на своих местах.

Answer (score 1):

Решение данной проблемы:
Нужно подключить в .scss файл compass

```
@import "compass/css3";
```